# How to change GNOME task switcher

Tags: gnome, taskbar

How to change the GNOME task switcher?

I want to change my task switcher on gnome to a different view
as mentioned in the below two images

Task switcher that i want to set.

[image: task switcher i want]

My current task switcher:

[image: my current task switcher]

The problem with my current task switcher is that I need to select below for apps having more than one window open, making my task switching experience a little bit annoying.

In the task switcher that I want we can switch tasks easily even for apps having more than one window open. I can't find way to get in on my device

Comment: Your pictures are all the same: not clear what you want to illustrate. Also mention Ubuntu version and thus corresponding Gnome Shell version. You find this in: Settings - About

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Gnome Shell, the **Window switcher** switches between individual windows, whereas the **Application switcher**, default in upstream Gnome Shell and in some Ubuntu versions, switches between applications.

You can disconnect the application switcher from the default keybindings with following configuration commands in the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "[]"
```

You can then enable the window switcher instead:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab', '<Super>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward  "['<Alt><Shift>Tab', '<Super><Shift>Tab']"
```

As a *bonus tip*, you could, if you wish, bind the Window switcher to e.g. `'<Alt>Tab'` and `'<Alt><Shift>Tab'` and the Application switcher to e.g. 'Tab' and 'Tab' by adapting the above commands accordingly.

As an *additional bonus tip*, you can also control whether the application and/or window switcher should display applications/windows on all workspaces (default for Application switcher), or on current workspace only (default for Window switcher).

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only true
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only false
```

To undo your changes and reset to default, you can reset any of these keys as for example in:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only
```

i.e., in any of the above commands, change `set` to `reset` and leave the value of the setting (last argument) out.

So you can customize this quite to your liking.

Comment: thankyou it worked :)